# How do I bind an object to a dynamically created label?

Tags: c#

I am trying to bind but it doesn't seem to be working :/

my code:

```
    void Binding(velocity Object, Label Output, string Field)
    {
        Binding newBinding = new Binding();
        newBinding.Source = Object;
        newBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        newBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(Field);
        Output.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, newBinding);
    }
            Binding(newProjectile.CurrentVelocity, lbl_CurrentVelOutput, "Magnitude"); // how i call it
```

Thanks a bunch!
edit: i dont get an errror, its just that on the output the label doesnt change.

edit: i have tried looking for how to implement the INotifyChange interface and got something like this

```
public class velocity : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler Handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (Handler != null)
        {
            Handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    public double Velocity
    {
        get { return Magnitude; }
        set
        {
            Magnitude = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("10");
        }
    }
```

but i have no idea what i am doing.

Comment: how your label binding looks like? any chance for more pieces of code?

Comment: What are `Object` and `Field`?

Comment: added the parameters

Comment: Is `Field` the name of a field or a property? (Bindings only work with properties.)

Comment: well there is a property in .CurrentVelocity for magnitude. am i doing it right?

Comment: `magnitude` or `Magnitude`? C# is case-sensitive. Other than that, the code should work, assuming that you're passing in the right Label instance.

Comment: yeah in my class it is Magnitude. for data binding. do i just need to run this code once and it will be permanently binded?

Comment: Oh wait, you said that the output doesn't change. Does your `velocity` class implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and does it raise a `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `Magnitude` property?

Comment: no i dont have that :o, what do i need to do?

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("10");` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding should work just fine, but if you want changes to that `Magnitude` property to automatically show up in your view, then you'll have to let WPF know about those changes. That's where the `INotifyProperty` interface comes in, as it allows your code to let WPF known which properties have been changed:

```
// In C#, the common convention is to give classes CamelCased names:
public class Velocity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // Local variables and method arguments are also camelCased,
        // but they start with a lower-case character:
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // Properties with default getters and setters automatically get a 'backing field',
    // but we can't use that because we need to call OnPropertyChanged, so we'll have to
    // manually write out things. Normally, you'd give the backing field a name similar
    // to the property, so it's obvious that they belong together:
    private double _magnitude;
    public double Magnitude
    {
        get { return _magnitude; }
        set
        {
            _magnitude = value;

            // Here, you need to pass in the *name* of the property that's being changed,
            // so WPF knows which views it needs to update (WPF can fetch the new value
            // by itself):
            OnPropertyChanged("Magnitude");
        }
    }
}
```